# What is a WScript in batch file?

Tags: javascript, batch-file, vbscript

Recently I saw some code like this, in a single `test.bat`:

```
@if (@This==@IsBatch) @then
@echo off
rem This is batch

wscript //E:JScript "%~dpnx0" %1

exit /b

@end

var http = WScript.CreateObject('Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0');

http.open("GET", "http://www.google.com/", false);
http.send();

if( http.status == 200) {
  var lines = http.responseText.split("\r\n");
  for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
    //...
  }
}

WScript.Quit(0);
```

I understand above part is a windows bat code, what is the js part?

Since there is  WScript, so I think it might be wscript code, then I searched, but it seems wscript looks like:

```vb
Dim x, y
Dim z  ‘ Can’t assign on same line
z = 10
If score = 100 Then _
  MsgBox "Great!"
```

And if I insert these wscript code into above code, it won't work.

And it is not js, I cannot do `console.log` nor `JSON.parse`

So, what on earth is above code?

Comment: It is [jscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript), not javascript. The `wscript code` you speak of is `vbscript`. You need `wscript.exe` (or cscript.exe) to execute vbscript code.

Comment: Change `//e:JScript` to `//e:vbscript`

Answer (score 2):

The [CScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cscript) is console interface to [Windows Scripting Host](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host). It's got support for multiple languages. There's parameter `/e:` that is used to specify if, say, JScript or VBScript, engine is being used. JScript is Microsoft's [own dialect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript) of JavaScript and there are quite a few differences.